# modulus of fourier series

Tags: summation, fourier-series

I have the following function
$$\left|a_0 + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m \cos(mx)\right|$$
Is there any way to rewrite such an equation as
$$\left|B_0\right| + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left|B_m\cos(mx)\right|$$
or something similar?

Comment: You can apply triangle inequality to get that: $$|a_0+\sum_{m = 1}^\infty A_m\cos(mx)|\leq |B_0|+\sum_{m = 1}^\infty |B_m\cos(mx)|$$
Generically, you can't expect to do better than this.

Comment: What do you mean by "modulus". It seems you want to simplify $\lvert a(x) \rvert$.

Comment: I would like to split the absolute value into many absolute values applied to each of the terms in the summation separately. I know this is no rule but I thought that maybe for sinusoids there would have been some rule (I am no mathematician though).